# Multiple Lambda functions from the sam.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

Still waiting for actual AWS support for this:
https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-samfarm/issues/5

How is this supposed to work?

My use case is I have an API Gateway fronted lambda that writes events to an SNS topic. I have another lambda that is subscribed to that topic.

Could these lambdas be in separate repos? Yes. Is part of the purpose of using a pub/sub pattern to separate these two applications in the first place? Yes.

But this is a simple app. The topic won't be shared with other functions and the whole thing is self contained. It should all be deployed together ideally all in the same template.

I can easily add all the functions I want to my SAM template but how do I deploy them? Should they each have a different CodeURI? That mean I need to script copying and install each lambdas dependencies into a different folder then point the CodeURIs for each lambda in the template to the different folder.

Is there any better support for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have as many `AWS::Serverless::Function` resources in a single template as you want as long as they have a unique logical id.

If you prefer to keep several lambda functions in a single repository you will have to provide different `CodeUri` for each lambda. For instance `CodeUri: ./handler-my-lambda-one.zip` and `CodeUri: ./handler-my-lambda-two.zip`.

Usually, it's a good practice to have a `Makefile` in your repository that would have a `build` target responsible for preparing `handler-my-lambda-*.zip` something like:

```
build: 
    rm -rf node_modules
    npm install
    zip -r handler.zip index.js lib node_modules
```

and a `deploy` target that would `package` your code (upload code to s3) and deploy cloudformation.

The `package` command is responsible for uploading the zip artifact specified in `CodeUri` and replace it with `s3` URL in the `sam.out.yaml`

```
deploy:
    aws cloudformation package \
        --template-file sam.yaml \
        --output-template-file sam.out.yaml \
        --s3-bucket my-artifact-bucket-name

    aws cloudformation deploy \
        --template-file sam.out.yaml
```

Since you decided to have multiple lambdas in a single repository probably you would have two `build` commands for each lambda function and some `cd ...` logic to change working directory per function